# Sort ArrayList of hashtables based on key within each hashtable

Tags: c#, collections, sorting

Let's say I have an ArrayList with a collection of hashtables as items - something like this:

```
Hashtable ht1 = new Hashtable();
ht1.add('position', 1);
ht1.add('trending', 2);

Hashtable ht2 = new Hashtable();
ht2.add('position', 2);
ht2.add('trending', 1);

...more of these with varying position & trending values

ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
arr.add(h1);
arr.add(h2);
...
```

initially the array is sorted by "position" and i print out the info with a simple loop

```
for(int x=0; x < arr.length; x++)
{
    Hashtable h = (Hashtable)arr[x];
    print(h["position"]);
}
```

next, i want to re-order the array by the "trending" and loop again.

is this possible to sort the array based on keys within each hashtable item?

Comment: Why are you not instead asking about sorting a `List<Dictionary<string, int>>`?

Comment: Why are you using non-generic collections? Use `List<T>` and `Dictionary<T1, T2>` and your code will be much simpler and will run faster.

Comment: also, you can just create a class if you only use trending and position keywords

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: two reasons: 1. i'm not very good with c# in general :( 2. i'm following behind someones code and that's currently how its setup - but yes, i'm open to any suggestions on how to change it

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok sorry about that. stack-asking newbie

Comment: Not a problem.  we caught the disease early. You should have many years of productive life here on [so] - without tags in your titles. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class AClass
{
    public int Position { set; get; }
    public int Trending { set; get; }
}
```

---

```
List<AClass> list = new List<AClass>() ;

list.Add(new AClass() { Position = 1, Trending = 2 });
list.Add(new AClass() { Position = 2, Trending = 1 });

var order1 = list.OrderBy(x => x.Position).ToArray();
foreach (var item in order1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Position);
}

var order2 = list.OrderBy(x => x.Trending).ToArray();
foreach (var item in order2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Position);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - any way to expand on this and use it in context of my example code? as i had commented, i'm not very experienced in c# (or coding in general) :( but learning as fast as i can thanks to help i get here. - thanks in advance

Comment: @Andre - Can you use a class to hold `Position` and `Trending` or do you need a Hashtable/Dictionary because you're dynamically loading key value pairs that aren't known ahead of time.

Comment: I know the key's ahead of time, meaning there is always a key "Position" and "Trending" in each hashtable within each array item. - thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck with 1.1, you'll want something like this;

```
class MyComparer : IComparer
{
    string key;
    public MyComparer(string key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((int)((Hashtable)x)[key]).CompareTo((int)((Hashtable)y)[key]);
    }
}
```

then you can call `arr.Sort(new MyComparer("trending"));`

When someone posts a solution using generics you'll see how much cleaner it is.

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to change it

create a class of the values you store in the hashtable

```
public class Item{
   public int Position { get; set; }
   public int Trending { get; set; }
}
```

create some instances of these classes in a generic list instead of ArrayList

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Item{ Position = 1, Trending = 2 });
items.Add(new Item{ Position = 2, Trending = 1 });
```

then you use lambda to sort the list

```
List<Item> listOrderByPosition = items.OrderBy(i => i.Position).ToList();
List<Item> listOrderByTrending = items.OrderBy(i => i.Trending).ToList();
```